# Extracting last match from a string with REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

I've created a simple text filter:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"- May 2019| - Jun 2019|- Jul 2019| - Aug 2019|- Sep 2019"); FALSE)
```

It should extract the month and year for an event from the cell A1. A1 contains a lot of text.

It works, but there's a problem: this filter grabs the first match while there can be several events described in A1. What is the proper way to request the last `REGEXEXTRACT` match from a string?

Comment: You need to give us data for `A1`. It makes no sense to talk without an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is my idea. But I think it's not a cute

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(
  REGEXREPLACE(A1,".*((Jul|Jun) 2019).*", "⚛$1"),
  "[^⚛]+$"
)
```

for the string `0dfsa sd - Jun 2019 sadfdf sdf - Jul 2019 asdfasdf - Augx`

There is another regexp `".*(Jun 2019|Jul 2019).*"` It also works fine.

My final fantasy is

```
=IF(
  ISERROR(
    REGEXEXTRACT(
      A1,
      "- May 2019| - Jun 2019|- Jul 2019| - Aug 2019|- Sep 2019")
  ),
  FALSE,
  REGEXEXTRACT(
    REGEXREPLACE(
      A1,
      ".*(- May 2019| - Jun 2019|- Jul 2019| - Aug 2019|- Sep 2019).*", "⚛$1"
    ),
    "[^⚛]+$"
  )
)
```

There is my [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0Q0XTk5eJDvpWF6XlDag2s4CjIJrilR_BvX__Fn6ks/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It works! Thank you. 

I understand the general logic behind the formulae, but I would like to get a better understanding of where "⚛$1" come from. Do you happen to have a guide for building these expressions? I tried to google it and failed.

Sorry if I ask simple questions but I'm totally new to this.

Comment: did not work for me... https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uVic.png

Comment: @user0 sorry, there was a missed `.*`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(- [A-Z][a-z]+ 2019)", "♦$1♦"), "♦")), "- ... 2019")), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset "&COUNTA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(- [A-Z][a-z]+ 2019)", "♦$1♦"), "♦"),  "- ... 2019")))-1, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Alright. Formula works fine and I understand it's logic up to 1 point: 
`"♦$1♦"), "♦"`
Newbie question: Is there some sort of glossary to make those expressions? I failed to google it.

Comment: it means "surround **the first group** with unique symbols ♦" where unique symbol can be anything you wish ♀♂♪♫♥♣♠... unfortunately, there is no good regex documentation, hut there are few on github that may be useful like: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax as for testing ground you can try: https://regex101.com